# Is there a way to find out details of data type erorr in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am pretty new to Snowflake Cloud offering and was just trying to load a simple .csv file from AWS s3 staging are to a table in Snowflake using copy command.

Here is what I used as the command:

copy into "database name"."schema"."table name"
    from @S3_ACCESS
    file_format = (format_name = format name);

When run the above code, I get the following error: Numeric value ['63'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzrRk.png) is not recognized

Please see the attached image. Not sure what this error is and i'm not able to find any lead in Snowflake UI itself to find out what could be wrong with the value.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says, it was waiting a numberic value, but it got "63", and this value can not be converted to numeric value.

From the image you share, I can see that there are some weird characters around 6 and 3. There could be an issue with file encoding or data is corrupted.

Please check encoding option for file format:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#format-type-options-formattypeoptions

By the way, I recommend you always use utf-8.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input Gokhan! I re-saved the file as CSV UTF8 format and was able to load it into Snowflake without any issue.